# Design view breaks as soon as I add any FragmentContainerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

Here you can see the split screen design view working when I comment out the FragmentContainerView:

[image]

And as soon as I uncomment it, the design view breaks

[image]

There are no errors as far as I can tell.

The full `xml`, just showing the structure and not the sibling content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activities.ParametersActivity" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
             <LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/colorLayout"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:visibility="gone"
                 android:orientation="vertical">
        
                  <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      />
             </LinearLayout>
         </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

What's interesting is that the `FragmentContainerView` *does* seem to actually be working when I build the app. So I bet this is just an Android Studio bug.

What can I do to debug and resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The layout error prompted by Android Studio is:- [image: Layout Error]

This can be resolved in the following ways:-

- If you are using the JetPack Navigation library and have a navGraph layout file, then specify it under the `app:navGraph` tag as :

```xml
        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

- If a single fragment is required to be displayed, then the same can be done by specifying its name under the `android:name` tag as :

```xml
        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:name="com.example.YourFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

- In the latter approach, however, as the error image says, a specific layout can not be shown by FragmentContainerView in edit mode. You can have a preview of the Fragment displayed by `tools:layout` tag.

```xml
        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:name="com.example.YourFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_your_fragment"/>
```

This should solve the problem, the layout is clearly visible on my IDE now!

Comment: Thanks very much. Unfortunately, in my case the Fragment View is rendering a Compose View, so it doesn't work even when I put `tools:layout`. But this approach does work for situations where you're not trying to wrap a Compose layout inside view XML.

Comment: The third solution worked for me. Thank you.