# Design Layout is missing after adding FragmentContainerView

Tags: android-studio

My design layout in android studio is missing after i add FragmentContainerView. Its worrking fine before, but after a while this happen. How to fix it?

[image: Before]

[image: After]

here is my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/img" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="com.DStudio.Finjer.MainFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What does the red error icon say when you click it or hover over it?

Comment: @ndriqa its just missing constraint and unknown fragment because i just add it, but i already did it right before without any warning and the bug still happening

Comment: can you post the relevant xml code?

Comment: Better explained [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75156622/design-view-breaks-as-soon-as-i-add-any-fragmentcontainerview]

Answer (score 0):

In the error panel there must be an option to "suppress the warning for this session". Once you do that your layout will show.